# integers adding instead of printing java

Tags: java, if-statement, integer, println

```
                if(a >= b && a >= c && b >= c) {
                    System.out.println(a + b + c);
                } else if(a >= b && a >= c && c >= b) {
                    System.out.println(a + c + b);
                } else if(b >= a && b >= c && a >= c) {
                    System.out.println(b + c + a);
                } else if(c >= a && c >= b && a >= b) {
                    System.out.println(c + a + b);
                } else if(c >= a && c >= b && b >= a) {
                    System.out.println(c + b + a);
                } else {
                        System.out.println ("Program not working!");
                    }
```

what do I need to make it just display the integers with one white space between them?

I tried google a bunch of times, but apparently I can't phrase it so that google can give me an answer.

I assume it's something just in the print line but I included my whole statement.

Comment: Add some String concatenation. `a + " " + b + " " + c`, otherwise its integer addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
System.out.println(c + b + a);
```

by

```
System.out.println(c + " " + b + " " + a);
```

Comment: Great thanks, now back to being terrible at my minor.

Comment: @PeterSteuber It worked for you so I suggest that you should accept the answer !!!